# refactor XML with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to move the `<sectionid/>` and the `<sponsor/>` elements inside the corresponding `<amendment/>`.

Here is an example:

From :

```
<root>
      <sectionid>A</sectionid>
      <sponsor>john</sponsor>
      <sponsor>paul</sponsor>
      <amendment>
            <id>1</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <sectionid>B</sectionid>
      <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
      <amendment>
            <id>5</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <id>4</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <sponsor>max</sponsor>
      <amendment>
            <id>6</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <id>7</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>

</root>
```

to:

```
<root>
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>A</sectionid>
            <sponsor>john</sponsor>
            <sponsor>paul</paul>
            <id>1</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>B</sectionid>
            <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
            <id>5</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>B</sectionid>
            <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
            <id>4</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>B</sectionid>
            <sponsor>max</sponsor>
            <id>6</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>B</sectionid>
            <sponsor>max</sponsor>
            <id>7</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>

</root>
```

Note 1: the `<section/>` element applies to all the `<amendments/>` before the next `<sectionid/>`

Note 2: the `<sponsor/>` element applies to all the `<amendments/>` before the next `<sponsor/>` list.

Note 3: The values of `//amendment/id` are not sequential.

How can this transformation be done with XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:param name="pSectionId"/>
        <xsl:param name="pSponsors"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pSectionId" select="$pSectionId"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pSponsors" select="$pSponsors"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="sectionid">
        <xsl:param name="pSectionId"/>
        <xsl:param name="pSponsors"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pSectionId" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pSponsors" select="$pSponsors"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="sponsor">
        <xsl:param name="pSectionId"/>
        <xsl:param name="pSponsors"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pSectionId" select="$pSectionId"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pSponsors" select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="sponsor[preceding-sibling::node()[1]/self::sponsor]">
        <xsl:param name="pSectionId"/>
        <xsl:param name="pSponsors"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pSectionId" select="$pSectionId"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pSponsors" select="$pSponsors|."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="amendment">
        <xsl:param name="pSectionId"/>
        <xsl:param name="pSponsors"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pSectionId|$pSponsors"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pSectionId" select="$pSectionId"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pSponsors" select="$pSponsors"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>A</sectionid>
        <sponsor>john</sponsor>
        <sponsor>paul</sponsor>
        <id>1</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>B</sectionid>
        <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
        <id>5</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>B</sectionid>
        <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
        <id>4</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>B</sectionid>
        <sponsor>max</sponsor>
        <id>6</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>B</sectionid>
        <sponsor>max</sponsor>
        <id>7</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
</root>
```

**Note**: Fine grained traversal. Linear complexity.

**Edit**: New input sample.

Comment: @Alejandro: The output I get with your transformation is not the one that you reported: Inside `<sectionid>A</sectionid>` I get only one sponsor -- "paul" -- not "john" and "paul".

Comment: @Dimitre: That is because you are running with Saxon preserving white space only text nodes. Added `xsl:strip-space` for Saxon.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="amendment">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vSectionId" 
          select="preceding-sibling::sectionid[1]"/>
     <xsl:variable name="vprevAmendment" 
          select="preceding-sibling::amendment[1]"/>

     <xsl:apply-templates select="$vSectionId" mode="copy"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vsectSponsors"
      select="preceding-sibling::sponsor
               [generate-id(preceding-sibling::sectionid[1])
               =
                generate-id($vSectionId)
               ]"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vamdSponsors"
      select="preceding-sibling::sponsor
               [generate-id(preceding-sibling::amendment[1])
               =
                generate-id($vprevAmendment)
               ]"/>


     <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
          select="$vamdSponsors|$vsectSponsors[not($vamdSponsors)]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="sectionid|sponsor"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
      <sectionid>A</sectionid>
      <sponsor>john</sponsor>
      <sponsor>paul</sponsor>
      <amendment>
            <id>1</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <sectionid>B</sectionid>
      <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
      <amendment>
            <id>5</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <id>4</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <sponsor>max</sponsor>
      <amendment>
            <id>6</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct results**:

```
<root>
   <amendment>
      <sectionid>A</sectionid>
      <sponsor>john</sponsor>
      <sponsor>paul</sponsor>
      <id>1</id>
      <text>some text</text>
   </amendment>
   <amendment>
      <sectionid>B</sectionid>
      <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
      <id>5</id>
      <text>some text</text>
   </amendment>
   <amendment>
      <sectionid>B</sectionid>
      <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
      <id>4</id>
      <text>some text</text>
   </amendment>
   <amendment>
      <sectionid>B</sectionid>
      <sponsor>max</sponsor>
      <id>6</id>
      <text>some text</text>
   </amendment>
</root>
```

Comment: I modified the sample to highlight a case where your current XSLT copies the wrong sponsors.