# get last group of previous-siblings with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to pull into an `<amendment/>` element the `<sectionid/>`, `<amendmenttext/>` and `<sponsor/>` elements if available.

Here is an example:

From :

```
<root>
      <amendment>
            <id>1</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <sectionid>A</sectionid>
      <sponsor>jon</sponsor>
      <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
      <amendment>
            <id>8</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <sectionid>B</sectionid>
      <sponsor>matt</sponsor>
      <sponsor>ben</sponsor>
      <amendmenttext>some intro text</amendmenttext>
      <amendment>
            <id>5</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <id>4</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <sponsor>max</sponsor>
      <amendment>
            <id>6</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <id>7</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>

</root>
```

to:

```
<root>
      <amendment>                
            <id>1</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>          
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>A</sectionid>
            <sponsor>jon</sponsor>
            <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
            <id>8</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>B</sectionid>
            <sponsor>matt</sponsor>
            <sponsor>ben</sponsor>
            <amendmenttext>some intro</amendmenttext>
            <id>5</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>B</sectionid>
            <sponsor>matt</sponsor>
            <sponsor>ben</sponsor>
            <id>4</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>B</sectionid>
            <sponsor>max</sponsor>
            <id>6</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>
      <amendment>
            <sectionid>B</sectionid>
            <sponsor>max</sponsor>
            <id>7</id>
            <text>some text</text>
      </amendment>

</root>
```

Note 1: the `<sectionid/>` element applies to all the `<amendments/>` before the next `<sectionid/>`

Note 2: the `<sponsor/>` element applies to all the `<amendments/>` before the next `<sponsor/>` list.

Note 3: The values of `//amendment/id` are not sequential.

Note 4: An `<amendment/>` could not have a `<sponsor/>` or `<sectionid/>` as a previous-sibling.

Note 5: `<amendmenttext>` only applies to the following `<amendment/>`

How can this transformation be done with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Modifications from previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096481/refactor-xml-with-xsl is a minor. I don't think it deserves a new question.

Comment: Oki. Not knowing that the solution would be similar. I thought it was not fair to the original responders to change the context of the question after they had answered. But point taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet (the same answer than before but just one rule):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:param name="pSectionId" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:param name="pSponsors" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:variable name="vSectionid" select="self::sectionid"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vSponsor" select="self::sponsor"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vAmendment" select="self::amendment"/>
        <xsl:if test="not($vSectionid|$vSponsor)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$pSectionId[$vAmendment]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$pSponsors[$vAmendment]"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pSectionId"
                           select="$pSectionId[not($vSectionid)]|$vSectionid"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pSponsors"
                            select="$pSponsors[not($vSponsor) or
                                               current()
                                                  /preceding-sibling::node()[1]
                                                     /self::sponsor] |
                                    $vSponsor"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <amendment>
        <id>1</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>A</sectionid>
        <sponsor>jon</sponsor>
        <sponsor>peter</sponsor>
        <id>8</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>B</sectionid>
        <sponsor>matt</sponsor>
        <sponsor>ben</sponsor>
        <id>5</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>B</sectionid>
        <sponsor>matt</sponsor>
        <sponsor>ben</sponsor>
        <id>4</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>B</sectionid>
        <sponsor>max</sponsor>
        <id>6</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
    <amendment>
        <sectionid>B</sectionid>
        <sponsor>max</sponsor>
        <id>7</id>
        <text>some text</text>
    </amendment>
</root>
```

**Note**: The diference from previous answer is the default empty node set expression for parameters in those rules wich is needed.

Comment: @Alejandro, I just added <amendmenttext/> to the sample XML.

Comment: @Benjamin Ortuzar: At this point you should know how to change this or previous answer accordingly. Lets see the modifications in this stylesheet: add parameter `pAmendmentText` with empty node set `/..` as defaut value, add variable `vAmendmentText` as `self::amendmenttest`, add this variable to the `xsl:if/@test` for skipping copy, add a `xsl:copy-of` instruction with `$pAmendmentText[$vAmendment]`, pass a `pAmendmentText` parameter with `$pAmendmentText[not($vAmendment)]|$vAmendmentText`